# Why am I getting an "Undefined control sequence" error with \includegraphics?

Tags: compilation-error

Here is the MWE that I would expect to compile and view as a pdf:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \includegraphics[width=5.0in]{mcs.eps}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

and although it is successfully compiling, the figure is not appearing in the pdf.  The space for the figure however, is appearing, so at least it appears that the figure is being recoginized, but not displayed.

I have confirmed that mcs.eps is in the same folder as the .tex file.  I also tried copying the .eps file to its own folder (named graphics) and tried:

```
\includegraphics[width=5.0in]{./graphics/mcs.eps}
```

as well as:

```
\includegraphics[width=5.0in]{./graphics/mcs}
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: You need to update your system (or at least the epstopdf-pkg). This was a short time error which has been resolved.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!  I replaced epstopdf-pkg.  It now compiles without error, but the figure is not appearing in the pdf.  That said, the space that the figure would take up is added, so at least it appears to be recognizing the dimensions of the figure.  I am on the most up-to-date version of TexMaker (5.0.4) if that helps.  Also, I note that the new epstopdf-pkg contains different files and file-types than my previous version.  Could that explain something?

Comment: texmaker is only an editor. What is your texsystem and how did you update epstopdf-pkg? Did you use the manager of your texsystem?

Comment: I am using MikTex 2.9.  To update epstopdf-pkg, I renamed the old file with -bak as a suffix, copied the updated file to the same location, did a "check for updates" in the console, and updated all the available options.  Under the list of packages, I can see that epstopdf-pkg was packaged on 2020-01-26 and installed today.  Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry but if you start to manually change your system it will be get difficult to help you. Why don't you simply use the miktex console and let it handle the update? That's what such tools are for.

Comment: Your edit has completely changed the problem, and now it disagrees with the title.  Please don't do that (and if there had been existing answers, we'd roll back your edit so that the answers still make sense).  If you must, ask a new question.